# Can't install emacs in Homebrew

Tags: installation, homebrew

```
$ brew install emacs
Updating Homebrew...
Warning: Treating emacs as a formula. For the cask, use homebrew/cask/emacs
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/emacs-27.1.mojave.bottle.1.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/edc19e2cbf4d5136f0e31adfb9c57161b65dd8163f861a92e10bfd617d1d611c--emacs-27.1.mojave.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> Pouring emacs-27.1.mojave.bottle.1.tar.gz
==> emacs cask is installed, skipping link.
==> Caveats
To have launchd start emacs now and restart at login:
  brew services start emacs
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  emacs
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/27.1: 4,009 files, 104.0MB
==> Upgrading 1 dependent:
cask 0.8.4 -> 0.8.5
==> Upgrading cask 0.8.4 -> 0.8.5
==> Downloading https://github.com/cask/cask/archive/v0.8.5.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://codeload.github.com/cask/cask/tar.gz/v0.8.5
######################################################################## 100.0%
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  RuntimeError: /usr/local/opt/emacs not present or broken
Please reinstall emacs. Sorry :(
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the output, it seems emacs actually got installed:

```
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/27.1: 4,009 files, 104.0MB
```

You should be able to use it straight away.

If you prefer [a GUI version](https://emacsformacosx.com/), you can install it with:

```
brew install --cask emacs
```

#### The problem

```
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  RuntimeError: /usr/local/opt/emacs not present or broken
Please reinstall emacs. Sorry :(
```

It's another tool, `cask`, which fails to install:

- It cannot find the emacs dir under `/usr/local/opt/emacs`.
- Homebrew installed it at `/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/27.1`.

#### The fix

You can fix it by:

1. (Recommended) Creating a symlink in `/usr/local/opt/` to emacs directory

```sh
$ brew link --overwrite emacs  # if it complains about relinking, run brew unlink emacs && brew link emacs instead
$ brew install cask
```

2. (Alternative) If the previous point didn't help, ignoring dependencies while installing `cask`

```sh
$ brew install cask --ignore-dependencies
```

Please let me know if it helped